# Can you delete extra space using ampscript if conditions are not met?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are creating an email that will populate a list of names for the recipient. However, each list will be a different length. Is there a way to delete the extra space created if the list only has 1 name on it versus 5?

The script below is what I am using, and this allows the content to populate correctly, but there is a big empty space if there is only 1 name instead of 5 names.

```
%%[var @GK2 set @GK2 = [Gatekeeper 2 Name]][var @GK2EM set @GK2EM = [Gatekeeper 2 Email]][var @GK3 set @GK3 = [Gatekeeper 3 Name]][var @GK3EM set @GK3EM = [Gatekeeper 3 Email]][var @GK4 set @GK4 = [Gatekeeper 4 Name]][var @GK4EM set @GK4EM = [Gatekeeper 4 Email]][var @GK5 set @GK5 = [Gatekeeper 5 Name]][var @GK5EM set @GK5EM = [Gatekeeper 5 Email]]%%

%%Gatekeeper 1 Name%% %%Gatekeeper 1 Email%%
%%[If @GK2 != " " Then]%%%%Gatekeeper 2 Name%% %%Gatekeeper 2 Email%%%%[EndIf]%% 
%%[If @GK3 != " " Then]%%%%Gatekeeper 3 Name%% %%Gatekeeper 3 Email%%%%[EndIf]%% 
%%[If @GK4 != " " Then]%%%%Gatekeeper 4 Name%% %%Gatekeeper 4 Email%%%%[EndIf]%% 
%%[If @GK5 != " " Then]%%%%Gatekeeper 5 Name%% %%Gatekeeper 5 Email%%%%[EndIf]%%
```

Comment: You could solve this by using a loop: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/29/loops-in-ampscript-and-server-side-javascript/

Comment: Thank you for your help!